# lower bound for $\|A x\|$ when $A$ is an invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix with real values. I know that if $A$ is symmetric then
$$
|\sigma_{\min}| \|x\|_2 \leq \| A x \|_2 
$$
where $\sigma_{\min}$ is the eigenvalue of $A$ with smallest absolute value. Does this estimate hold even if $A$ is not symmetric? Any comments appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you replace *"eigenvalue of $$ with smallest absolute value"* with smallest [singular value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value). Note that if $A$ is normal matrix, then the singular values are equal to the absolute values of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider  $A=\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right]$, $x=\left[\begin{matrix}
1  \\
 1
\end{matrix}\right]$.